# Issue in executing @After in Cucumber-JVM - Appium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, cucumber-jvm

I am working on a framework, built using Appium, Cucumber-JVM.

Below is a snippet on how I instantiate a appium driver:

```
     private WebDriverFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets the factory instance.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static WebDriverFactory getInstance() {
        if (factory == null)
            factory = new WebDriverFactory();
        return factory;
    }


    public AppiumDriver getAppiumDriver() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {

        if (appiumDriver == null || !isSessionActive(appiumDriver)) {


......instantiate driver......

}return appiumDriver;
}

   */
    private boolean isSessionActive(AppiumDriver driver) {
        return !driver.toString().contains("(null)");
//        return driver.getCapabilities()!=null?true:false;
    }


    public void closeAppiumDriver() {
        if ( (appiumDriver != null || isSessionActive(appiumDriver)) ) {
            appiumDriver.closeApp();
            appiumDriver.quit();
            if (appiumService != null)
                if (appiumService.isRunning())
                    appiumService.stop();
        }
        factory = null;
        appiumDriver = null;
    }
```

Now, In my stepDefs I have placed Cucumber @After hook like below but its sporadically giving me Nullpointerexecption

> Error : java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at appiumdriver.WebDriverFactory.isSessionActive(WebDriverFactory.java:146)
>           at appiumdriver.WebDriverFactory.closeAppiumDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:159)
>           at stepDefs.AndroidTestsCommonStepDefs_usingFactory.teardown(AndroidTestsCommonStepDefs_usingFactory.java:140)

```
    @After
public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
    try {
        byte[] screenshot = WebDriverFactory.getInstance().getAppiumDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

    } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformDontsupportSnapshot) {
        System.err.println(somePlatformDontsupportSnapshot.getMessage());
    }
}


@After
public void teardown() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
    System.out.println("Ran the tearDown.");
    WebDriverFactory.getInstance().closeAppiumDriver();
}
```

I have tried putting above teardown() code in @AfterClass tag inside Cucumber runner, but it was not getting triggered everytime. Also, I am unable to use @After in Cucumber Runner class.

How to deal with this kind of scenario?
Also, In future I might want to instantiate different device in driver, as part of test suite so, triggering driver.closeApp(); & setting driver = null; is going to be crucial for me.

Kindly advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently both the After hooks can run in any order. Therefore you are getting the exception intermittently. You need to use the order attribute in the After annotation to make sure the driver closure is performed last.

In case of After the order attribute value which is higher is executed first before the one with the lower value. Opposite behaviour for Before annotation.

For embed method you can use `@After(order=20)` and for driver closure `@After(order=10)`

Comment: Sure. I will try that. but do you see any problem in below code, as its ultimately pointing to this place:    private boolean isSessionActive(AppiumDriver driver) {
        return !driver.toString().contains("(null)");